# search function double return value possible

Tags: c

I'm writing a search function. Parameters are:

`(char *array, char to_find)`

```
char search (char *array, char to_find)
{
int counter;
for (counter =0; array[counter]!='\0'; counter++)
{ if (to_find==array[counter])
  return 2; 
else return 0;
}
}

int main()
{
char *word[100]="woman";
char letter;
scanf("%c" &letter);
if (search(word, letter)==1)
{ 
printf("match")}

}
```

I'd like to know if it also possible to modify this code to return 2 values; if true, return 1 & counter. for example I have tried:

```
    char search (char *array, char to_find)
    {
    int counter;
    for (counter =0; array[counter]!='\0'; counter++)
    { if (to_find==array[counter])
      return 2; 
    else return 0;

    }
    }
char searchindex(char *array, char to_find)
{ int counter;
for (counter=0; array[counter]!='\0'; counter++)
{
if (to_find==array[counter])
{
return counter;
}
else return -1;
}



int main()
    {
    char *word[100]="woman";
    char letter;
    int position;
    scanf("%c" &letter);

    /**I tried representing the return values as integers**/
int test1= search(word, letter);
int test2= searchindex(word, letter);
if ((test1+test2)>0) 
{printf(match);} /**this had errors but i can't seem to find them**/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First notice that your `if-else` statement seems strange. You have:

```
char search (char *array, char to_find)
{
    int counter;
    for (counter =0; array[counter]!='\0'; counter++)
    { 
        if (to_find==array[counter])
            return 2; 
        else return 0;  // This strange....
    }

}
```

which means that you will always return after the first compare. You probably want:

```
char search (char *array, char to_find)
{
    int counter;
    for (counter =0; array[counter]!='\0'; counter++)
    { 
        if (to_find==array[counter])
            return 2; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then you ask:

> …  possible to modify this code to return 2 values

No, in C it's only possible to directly return one value. However, there is a number of ways to "return" multiple values.

For instance by passing a pointer to a variable and then change the value using the pointer. Like:

```
char search (char *array, char to_find, int* counter)
{
    for (*counter = 0; array[*counter]!='\0'; (*counter)++)
    { 
        if (to_find==array[*counter])
            return 2; 
    }    
    return 0;
}

// Call it like
int counter;
int test1= search(word, letter, &counter);
```

Another way is to make a struct and return the struct. Like:

```
struct X {
    int result;
    int counter;
};

struct X search (char *array, char to_find)
{
    struct X res;
    for (res.counter = 0; array[res.counter]!='\0'; res.counter++)
    { 
        if (to_find==array[res.counter])
        {
            res.result = 2;
            return res;
        } 
    }    
    res.result = 0;
    return res;
}

// Call it like
struct X test1= search(word, letter, &counter);
```